# View Sitecore Analytics In Real Time

Tags: xconnect, experience-profile

I'm using Sitecore 9 update 2.

I'm trying to see if hitting a jss endpoint (`layout service` endpoint specifically) captures analytics data just by virtue of hitting the endpoint or not.

I also have a custom endpoint that I'm trying to use Sitecore's tracker in (`Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current`). I planned on using the `experience profile` in order to view the results however I'm seeing a delay to get user data to show up in there (~30 minutes) even when I force a session to end which should start collecting the user's session data.

Is there some kind of dev/local mode I can configure `experience profile` to use that can show visitor data in real time? If there isn't is there a way to see real time analytic data in my `xconnect` site as it happens?

Comment: I believe that rebuilding of XConnect Search index could do the trick for you. Please try to follow this guideline https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-search-indexer/rebuild-index/rebuild-solr-index.html. You see data only when they are indexed. I will post more detailed answer once you confirm that it is working for you.

Comment: Another option would be to decrease interval which XConnect Search Indexer is indexing data. I don't know whether there is setting like this as I couldn't find any mention of this quickly in documentation. You could check in config files. Maybe you find something

Comment: By default the indexer will show the data within seconds. It is only in an unhealthy system that this wouldn’t be the case.

Comment: If you have reproduced it in a dev box, you might want to capture the requests sent to XConnect in fiddler. This would let you isolate whether the data really is sent when you expect it to.

Comment: @PeterProchazka I'm not sure why but after doing that it looks like data is showing up as soon as I abandon my session after navigating through a few normal pages. Assuming updates are coming through it looks like hitting JSS's layout endpoint does not cause analytics to be captured though.

Comment: That is then another problem regarding JSS. Please create a separate question for that with some clarification.

Comment: @PeterProchazka yep will do. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Teeknow Gladly. I will post detailed answer tomorrow.